How to write an automated test for a lifespan event in FastAPI
I have a Fast API website where I have a lifespan event run:
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Starting up IAM APP
    if mm_settings.MIGRATE_CONFIGURATION:
        await migrate_configuration_service_providers()
    yield


app = FastAPI(root_path=mm_settings.ROOT_PATH, lifespan=lifespan)

I want to write automated tests that ensure that migrate_configuration_service_providers() and the functions in it are called. However all the tests I write fail.
I have tried with both httpx.AsyncClient and FastAPI TestClient:
class LifespanTestBase(AsyncTestBase):
    @pytest.fixture()
    def test_client(self):
        with TestClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as client:
            yield client

    @pytest_asyncio.fixture()
    async def async_client(self):
        async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as client:
            yield client

And the tests:
class TestLifespan(LifespanTestBase):
    @patch("iam.util.migrations.migrate_configuration_service_providers")
    # @pytest.mark.asyncio
    def test_should_call_migrate_configuration_service_providers(
        self,
        migrate_configuration_service_providers_mock: Mock,
        test_client: TestClient,
    ):
        test_client.get("/")
        migrate_configuration_service_providers_mock.assert_called()

    @patch("iam.util.migrations.migrate_configuration_service_providers")
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_should_call_migrate_configuration_service_providers2(
        self,
        migrate_configuration_service_providers_mock: Mock,
        async_client: AsyncClient,
    ):
        await async_client.get("/")
        migrate_configuration_service_providers_mock.assert_called()

Both tests fail. Meanwhile when I run the application manually, the migrate_configuration_service_providers() runs (I see the changes in the database). But I would like to have automated tests that do the check. Is it possible to write automated tests in this case?
Edit
Could the problem in the tests have something to do with the fact that the app variable doesn't have any routers attached, so when I say
with TestClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as test_client:
  test_client.get("/")

I get a 404 instead of a 200?

Seems like lifespan event triggered when TestClient or AsyncClient is instantiated so patch occurs after client(and thus the lifespan event) already executed.
try this out:
from unittest.mock import patch
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

def test_should_call_migrate_configuration_service_providers():
    with patch("iam.util.migrations.migrate_configuration_service_providers") as migrate_configuration_service_providers_mock:
        with TestClient(app=app,base_url="http://test") as test_client:
            test_client.get("/")
        migrate_configuration_service_providers_mock.assert_called()

Here I instantiate TestClient inside of a patch

Doesn't work unfortunately. I still get AssertionError: Expected 'migrate_configuration_service_providers' to have been called

I see. Please, try to change path location to lifespan instead of location of this migration. e.g. iam.lifespan.migrate_configuration_service_providers.

That doesn't work either, it gives the error that function lifespan doesn't have migrate_configuration_service_providers. Why would that even work anyway? migrate_configuration_service_providers is not in a module name iam.lifespan

You should specify in your patch path to module where function should be mocked. If your lifespan function in iam.lifespan.py then you should specify iam.lifespan.migrate_configuration_service_providers

This last turned out to be the solution, together with using LifespanManager to trigger the lifespan event

Found the solution, it consisted of 2 things:

I had to use asgi-lifespan manager to trigger the lifespan event
Because I was importing the migrate_configuration_service_providers() into where the lifespan method was as from iam.util.migration import migrate_configuration_service_providers, I had to patch it where the lifespan method was defined. So since lifespan was defined in module iam.main: patch("iam.main.migrate_configuration_service_providers")

For more details, if anyone is interested, look at the answer to my second question on the subject
